# Role of fibre components in optical schemes

Tags: optics, laser

Where can I find a sense of use of concrete fibre optical items in any optical scheme?

For example, what does a **multiplexer** do in any scheme? And what does a **optical add-drop multiplexer** do in any scheme?

I would like to get an information about all similar fibre items (**polarization controller** and so on).

Also please write **references to sources**, where you will find this information.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you asking these questions in the context of telecommunications?

Comment: You need to get yourself a textbook on fiber optical communication. As is, the question is way too broad (and it's engineering and not physics, anyway).

Comment: @CuriousOne, agreed. I gave a brief overview in my answer and it took me practically 45 minutes to find all the information he wanted.

Comment: @heather: That looks like a labour of love... nothing stops you from doing that, of course, even though the OP seems to be simply too lazy to do it himself.

Comment: @heather: I am asking these questions in the context of **fibre lasers**.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov, is my answer invalid, then? I think it answers your questions anyway...please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is really broad, I'm only going to cover a couple of fiber optical items, give the resources I used, and give a few more general resources you can use to look into other items.

**Concrete Fiber Optical Item Descriptions:**

- A **multiplexer** is used for multiplexing (though it can be used in electronic switching).

  > multiplexing (sometimes contracted to muxing) is a method by which multiple analog or digital signals are combined into one signal over a shared medium. The aim is to share an expensive resource.$^1$

  There are multiple ways this can be done; the one relevant to optical communications is frequency-division multiplexing, which sends the signals at distinct wavelengths in the same medium. This is inherently an analog technology. A variant of this, wavelength division multiplexing, is used in optical communications. Below is a diagram of frequency-division multiplexing:

[image: frequency-division multiplexing] See note one for source.

Below is a diagram of an optical multiplexer:

[image: optical multiplexer] (Source is [this website](http://www.intechopen.com/books/advances-in-optical-fiber-technology-fundamental-optical-phenomena-and-applications/recent-advances-in-wavelength-division-multiplexing-plastic-optical-fiber-technologies).)

It takes in the input wavelengths of laser light, combines them, and sends them. A demuxer, on the other side of the cable, will split them into their wavelengths and then send them where they need to go.

- **Wavelength division multiplexing**

  > multiplexes a number of optical carrier signals onto a single optical  fiber by using different wavelengths (i.e., colors) of laser light.$^2$

  So wavelength division multiplexing is basically a form of frequency-division multiplexing that specifically uses laser light to send the information through an optical fiber. Below is a diagram of wavelength division multiplexing:

[image: wavelength division multiplexing] (See note two for source.)

- **Polarization controllers** allow one to modify the polarization state of light (polarization references the orientation of the electric field, as light is electromagnetic radiation and the magnetic field is perpendicular to the electric field). They can

  > be operated without feedback, typically by manual adjustment or by electrical signals from a generator, or with automatic feedback. $^3$

  These are necessary because they can combine two wavelengths, delete a wavelength, etc. The symbol for a polarization controller is shown below:

[image: polarization controller] (See third note for source.)

- An **optical attenuator**

> is a device used to reduce the power level of an optical signal, either in free space or in an optical fiber. $^4$

The symbol for a (variable) optical attenuator is shown below (there are multiple types of optical attenuator):

[image: optical attenuator] (See note four for source.)

- Finally, an **optical add-drop multiplexer**

> is a device used in wavelength-division multiplexing systems for multiplexing and routing different channels of light into or out of$^5$

an optical fiber. In other words, it is sort of like the traffic director of optical fibers. A diagram of one is shown below:

[image: optical add-drop multiplexer] (See note five for source.)

**Sources:**

$^1$Multiplexing information (and image) was from [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing).

$^2$Wavelength-division multiplexing (and image) was from [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength-division_multiplexing).

$^3$Information on polarization controllers (and image) was from [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_controller).

$^4$Information on optical attenuators (and image) was from [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_attenuator).

$^5$Information on optical add-drop multiplexers (and image) was from [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_add-drop_multiplexer).

**Here are several more general sources on fiber-optic communications, fiber-optics, and fiber lasers** (several are textbooks):

- [This website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-optic_communication) isn't nearly as in-depth as the textbooks, but it is on a simpler level.This is a fiber-optic communications site.
- The textbook *Fiber-Optic Communication Systems, 4th Edition* by Govind P. Agrawal (here it is [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470505117))
- The textbook *Fiber Optic Communications* by James Downing (here it is [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401866352))
- [This website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_laser) isn't super in-depth, but it might help you...it's about fiber lasers (added in light of your comment).
- The textbook *Introduction to High Power Fiber Lasers* by R. Andrew Motes (here it is [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0979368731))
- The book *Fiber Lasers* by Oleg G. Okhotnikov (here it is [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3527411143))
- [This website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber) isn't super in-depth, but it might help you...it's about optical fibers.
- The book *Understanding Fiber Optics* by Jeff Hecht (here it is [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131174290))

Hope this helps! (In the future, please don't ask such broad questions. I've given a brief overview here.)

Comment: Where did you see the frequency division multiplexing being done in optical fibers (apart from the implementation in form of wavelength division multiplexing)? Fibers are generally being operated in a purely digital mode because the lasers can't be modulated in a linear fashion (one can use a feedback scheme with a photodiode up to a few MHz, but that would undercut the otherwise achievable bandwidth of the fiber by five orders of magnitude). Even the FDM schemes for cable and Wifi are today done digitally, anyway (basically everything is).

Comment: Frequency division multiplexing (in its pure form) isn't done in optical fibers. I mentioned it due to the fact that wavelength division multiplexing is a subdivision of frequency division multiplexing.

Comment: @heather: Have you found only these links? Do other references exist?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov I am adding more references even now, actually. A couple of the websites I cited are Wikipedia websites, and you can look at the sources there. The textbooks will also probably have suggested reading. As I said, I'm continuing to add links.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov I've cited all my sources, and I've added a bunch of reference links. There are more out there, but I think the list I made will probably suffice for now.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov here's some info that'll help you on physics.SE: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.